# Does Do-Not-Disturb mode silence your phone's alarms?

Tags: ios

If I turn on Do-Not-Disturb, will it also silence my phone alarms?

Comment: what's preventing you to check this?

Comment: same thing that prevented you.  You could have made easy points @casey_miller!

Comment: I prefer showing how to solve problems rather than just solve the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Simply put:* No, it does not.

I suppose this prevents an alarm not going off when you really need it to (i.e. waking you up).

Answer (score 1):

This is from Apples website:

> Turn on Do Not Disturb to suppress all incoming calls and notifications. Enable it  manually or schedule a recurring time. Or allow calls from your favorites or specific contact groups.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help?